# How to say every property inside this object is a string

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am writing a type definition file (.d.ts) in typescript. Where I want to specify "every property inside of this object is a string", something like this:

```
interface IThings {
  thing: string{}
}
```

however this won't work. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types):

```
interface IThings {
    [name: string]: string;
}
```

Then:

```
let a = {} as IThings;
a["x1"] = "y"; // ok
a["x2"] = 4; // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IThings%20%7B%0D%0A%09%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20IThings%3B%0D%0Aa%5B%22x1%22%5D%20%3D%20%22y%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%0D%0Aa%5B%22x2%22%5D%20%3D%204%3B%20%2F%2F%20Type%20'number'%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20type%20'string'))